# AngularJS - GET object by ID

Tags: angularjs, getelementbyid

I want to get object from database by ID. I succeed to get all of the objects, but I have trouble with sending id as parameter. Here is my HTML code for all of the items:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='event in events'>
          <td>{{event.name}}</td>
          <td>{{event.date}}</td>
          <td>{{event.createdBy}}</td>
          <td><button role='button' class='btn' ng-click="editEvent(event)" data-toggle="modal" href="#editModal">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
    var app = angular.module('votr', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: 'event-list.html', controller: 'EventListCtrl'})
    });

    app.factory('EventService', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/api/events/:id');
    });

    app.controller('EventListCtrl', function($scope, $location, EventService) {
      EventService.query(function(events){
          $scope.events = events;
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get object by id use the following:

`EventService.get({id:your_id})`

Also take look at **[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)**